# What kind of series is this, and how do I sum it?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\displaystyle\sum{\frac1{a_n}}$, e.g.
$$\frac 1 1 + \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 3 + \frac 1 4 + \dots + \frac 1 n$$  or
$$\frac 1 2 + \frac 1 4 + \frac 1 6 + \frac 1 8 + \dots + \frac 1 {2n}$$

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for *harmonic numbers*. An excellent article can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). The corresponding (diverging) series is the [harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29). To sum it, use the integral representation given in the first article:

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{1 - x^n}{1 - x}\,{\rm d}x = \int_0^1 (1 + x + \cdots + x^{n-1})\ {\rm d}x = 1 + \frac12 + \cdots + \frac1{n} = H_n$$

Maybe if it's not clear the left one you mentioned is $H_n$, the right one is obviously $\frac12\cdot H_n$.

Answer (score 2):

That is a [harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29). You can approximate it by integration, as explained in the link. Note that if $n \to \infty$, the sum diverges.

Answer (score 2):

A nice approximation for $n \to \infty$ can be derived from

$$\eqalign{
  & \log \left( {1 + x} \right) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}\frac{{{x^{k + 1}}}}{{k + 1}}}  = x - \frac{{{x^2}}}{2} + \frac{{{x^3}}}{3} -  +  \cdots   \cr 
  & \log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}\frac{1}{{{n^{k + 1}}}}\frac{1}{{k + 1}}}  = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{{2{n^2}}} + \frac{1}{{3{n^3}}} -  +  \cdots  \cr} $$

$$\log \left( {n + 1} \right) - \log n = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}\frac{1}{{{n^{k + 1}}}}\frac{1}{{k + 1}}}  = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{{2{n^2}}} + \frac{1}{{3{n^3}}} -  +  \cdots $$

If we sum for $n=1,2,3,\dots,m $ we have

$$\log \left( {m + 1} \right) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^m {\frac{1}{n}}  - \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^m {\frac{1}{{{n^2}}}}  + \frac{1}{3}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^m {\frac{1}{{{n^3}}}}  -  +  \cdots $$ or

$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^m {\frac{1}{n}}  - \log \left( {m + 1} \right) = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^m {\frac{1}{{{n^2}}}}  - \frac{1}{3}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^m {\frac{1}{{{n^3}}}}  +  -  \cdots $$

If we let $m\to \infty$ , we have that

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{m \to \infty } \left[ {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^m {\frac{1}{n}}  - \log \left( {m + 1} \right)} \right] = \frac{1}{2}\zeta \left( 2 \right) - \frac{1}{3}\zeta \left( 3 \right) + \frac{1}{4}\zeta \left( 4 \right) -  +  = \sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^n}\frac{{\zeta \left( n \right)}}{n}} $$

where $$\zeta \left( n \right) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{{k^n}}}} $$

The value of the right hand side is know as Euler's constant, $\gamma \approx 0.577$, and this result tells us that for large values of $m$, we can approximate the $m$th harmonic number by

$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^m {\frac{1}{n}}  \sim \log \left( {m + 1} \right) + \gamma $$